# Powershell script only runs in certain scenarios

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have a functions that only works on some scensarios.

- It works on Powershell ISE, but when I save the same thing in a .Ps1 file and run it, it doest not work.
- I have the function as part of a big script. It works and open the Window when I run it on Windows 7 but doest not run on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Why?

The script with the function and its calling is:

```
Function Get-SaveFileTxt($initialDirectory) 
{ 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | 
Out-Null 

$SaveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog 
$SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory 
$SaveFileDialog.AddExtension = $true 
$SaveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "txt" 
$SaveFileDialog.filter = "Text Files (*.txt)| *.txt" 
$SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null 
$SaveFileDialog.filename 
} 

Get-SaveFileTxt
```

Comment: _"it does not work"_? Be more specific on what error you get, please.

Comment: @tbergstedt Try it. The script remains execution without error, apparently nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the case here but I remember a bug that the opened dialog doesn't take focus and appear behind other opened windows. Can you confirm?

UPDATE:

Set the ShowHelp property to $true.

```
$SaveFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
```

It works in the ISE because ISE's apartment state is STA by default and your powershell mode is MTA, you can check it with:

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ApartmentState
```

Your code will work if you open powershell in STA mode:

```
powershell.exe -STA
```

Comment: Thank you @Shay. It does not look to open an reamain behind, looks like nothing happens.

Comment: interesting. What do ShowHelp propertly exactly?
It totally changes the interface, With Showhelp in false the form looks like this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/300838/false.png with true look like this https://dl.dropbox.com/u/300838/true.png

Comment: It's hard for me to explain, this is something that relates to developers (which I'm not), from what I can tell it is required when you work with GUI.